# Null property when binding to empty array in appsettings.json

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, configuration

I stumbled across an issue when using the [Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0) pattern where model properties are being set to `null` when bound to an empty JSON array.

*appsettings.json*:

```json
{
  "MyOptions": {
    "Values": []
  }
}
```

*MyOptions.cs*:

```cs
public sealed class MyOptions
{
  public IEnumerable<string> Values { get; set; }
}
```

*Startup.cs*:

```cs
...
services.Configure<MyOptions>(                            
  _configuration.GetSection(nameof(MyOptions));
...
```

The above configuration successfully builds and injects an `IOptions<MyOptions>` when required, however `Values` property is set to `null` rather than an empty enumerable. This would cause the following code to throw a `NullReferenceException`:

```cs
public class MyService
{
  public MyService(IOptions<MyOptions> options)
  {
    var values = options.Value.Values;

    foreach (var val in values)
    {
      // Do something
    }
  }
}
```

This has been raised as an issue on the dotnet repo (https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/1341) although MS seem to have closed it as "working as designed".

Is there a workaround to prevent the `NullReferenceException` being thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always make sure my properties inside a configuration class have meaningful default values assigned:

```cs
public sealed class MyOptions
{
  public IEnumerable<string> Values { get; set; } = Array.Empty<string>();
}
```

This way I don't have to check for `null` or not configured values each time I'm using my configuration object.

Comment: I prefer this approach to mine, it's a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

I think that MS gave a right answer "working as designed". You have allways remember Murphy's Law - anything that can go wrong will go wrong. To create  the robust code anyone should expect null value for any nullable property, doesn't matter how it was init. It can always became null somewhere on the way. So I am always checking for null

```
  if (options.Value.Values != null)
    foreach (var val in options.Value.Values)
    {
       // Do something
    } else ... return error;
```

I don' t know how myoptions are important for this application, but I usually  check appdata data in startup already

```
var myOptions = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(MyOptions));
if (myOptions.Exists())
{
    services.Configure<MyOptions>(myOptions);
    services.AddScoped(typeof(MyService));
} else ... return error
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround is to alter the `MyOptions` class to use backing fields instead of auto-properties and in the getter a [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) to return an empty `IEnumerable`:

```cs
public sealed class MyOptions
{
  private IEnumerable<string> _values;

  public IEnumerable<string> Values
  {
    get => _values ?? new List<string>();
    set => _values = value;
  }
}
```